# Handling an ActiveRecord error if database is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, controllers

I'm working on a rails 4 app, and i have the following controller code

```
 def index
  @issue = Issue.find(1)
  @sections = @issue.sections
  @articles = @issue.articles
 end
```

which breaks if the database is empty with the error: "Couldn't find Issue with id=1". What is the proper way to check for this in a way that if nothing is in the db it doesn't raise an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method you can use is the `exists?` active record method, like so:

```
@issue = Issue.where(id: 1)

if @issue.exists?
    # do something if it exists
else
    # do something if it is missing
end
```

Side note: Since you're attempting to find by `id`, you don't necessarily need the `.where` portion; you can simply do: `Issue.exists?(1)`.

[`exists?` documentation on APIDoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases such exception is expected and recommenced. For example, you can rescue it with a custom 404 page.

Anyway, if you really don't want that, you can use `find_by` method which will output nil if nothing found

```
@issue = Issue.find_by(id: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can handle that exception in your controller

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found
def record_not_found
 flash[:alert] = "invalid information"
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

or you can use a where clause

```
@issue = Issue.where(id: 1).first
```

now check for nil by

```
@issue.nil?
```