# Ruby on Rails ignoring If Else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

My Ruby on Rails 3 controller has a simple If Else statement that seems to not work.

My Statements:

```
def create
if @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
  @trained.first.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
else
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  if @trained.save
        @trained.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
  end
end

redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path

end
```

This is the log with the error, NoMethodError for 'update_attributes' but this line should not run since it cannot find the Certificate with user_id '1'. 
Why doesn't it do the else statement?

```
Started POST "/certificates" for 50.241.102.234 at 2014-01-06 07:01:55 -0800
Processing by CertificatesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TM6GPqslIs013O+mOuxGXyyD90T2O5lSZmnqKTFPwVw=", "certificate"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Train"}
Certificate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `certificates`.* FROM `certificates` WHERE `certificates`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/certificates_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The `where` clause will never return nil**, it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object, **that can be empty**!

Try this instead:

```
def create
  if @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first
    @trained.update_attributes(attend: "No")
  else
    @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
    if @trained.save
      @trained.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
    end
  end

  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
```

but I would refactor my code to something like this:

```
def create
  @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first
  @trained ||= Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  if @trained.persisted? # tests if the records is persisted in the DB (has an ID)
    @trained.attend = "No"
  else
    @trained.attend = "Yes"
  end

  @trained.save
  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
```

The very short version:

```
def create
  @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first || Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  @trained.attend = @trained.persisted? ? "No" : "Yes"
  @trained.save

  redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
```

---

For the record (@NitinJ please take a look), you can assign a variable in a if condition:

```
if first_user = User.first
# if User.first does not returns nil, executes the first block with local variable first_user available
  first_user.id 
else
  # User.first returned nil
end
```

Comment: you are making an assignment in if condition

Comment: So what's the problem? It still does the check of the nil: `if a = nil` still works. Please test it yourself @NitinJ

Comment: So many downvotes, please be constructive & provide a reason at least!

Comment: yes this works i tested. i am little bit confused when putting assignment in if clause

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thank you for all your suggestions. I will be looking into your other options. Your initial answer worked perfectly.

Comment: @NitinJ, several languages, including Ruby, C/C++, Java, and others allow assignment in an `if` clause. It works because, in those languages that support it, the assignment statement itself returns a value, which is the value assigned. The `if` evaluates the value for truthiness.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @mbratch and MrYoshiji do not take that offensive :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
```

The above statement returns a Relation, which is never `nil`, so the condition will always be `true`, even if the relation is empty

If you expecting 0 or 1 result, you can use

```
if @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).first
   #...
```

If you're expecting 0 or several results, you can use (not very elegant):

```
if (@trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id]).to_a) && @trained.any?
   #...
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigned value in if condition

```
@trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
```

change it to

```
@trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
if @trained.exists?
else
end
```

Comment: @mbratch take a look again i have updated my answer .

Comment: Also the convention wants us to use `@trained.present?` to test it, `.exists?` is an ActiveRecord function

Comment: there are many ways to check with .blank? .empty? i choose exists :)

Comment: @mbratch i am not a geek of RUBY i am learning and i am really thankful to you for sharing your knowlege. please check the accepted answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909385/handling-an-activerecord-error-if-database-is-empty/20909442#20909442

Comment: Ah Ok, I just tried it, too. It's just not in that doc. To me, `empty?` is a more descriptive adjective, though. It's not checking whether the Relation exists (it does indeed exist (not nil), it's just empty) but rather that it's empty. But that's just semantics. ;)